# Delete 1 row per 2 rows of multiple matching conditions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have several columns of data 3 are key columns a b and c

I need to check for values in col A that are less then 1.5

i need to check for duplicate values in col B only on the rows that are less then 1.5 in col A  then compare these rows to Col C if C also has duplicate values where A&B conditions are met then remove 1 duplicate where 2 ab&c conditions are met

example.

```
   A        B         C

1  1/4   30  1/2     30
1  1/4   30  1/2     30  
1  1/4   30  1/2     30
1  1/4   30  1/2     30 
1  1/4   30          31
1  1/4   28  1/4     31
1  1/4   30  1/2     31
1  1/4   11 14/45    32
1  1/4   11 14/45    32
1  1/4   13  1/2     35
1  1/2   21          33
1  1/2   21          33
```

After running

```
   A        B         C

1  1/4   30  1/2     30
1  1/4   30  1/2     30
1  1/4   30          31
1  1/4   28  1/4     31
1  1/4   30  1/2     31
1  1/4   11 14/45    32
1  1/4   13  1/2     35
1  1/2   21          33
```

current code has logic errors no debug info. I also do not know how to only delete 1 row per set of duplicates from here.

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lrow2 As Long
Dim GotMatch As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim l As Long


    lrow = Range("H:H,Q:Q").End(xlUp).Row
    lrow2 = Range("P:P").End(xlUp).Row

          For i = 8 & 17 To lrow
          For l = 16 To lrow2
                If Cells(i, 8 & 17) <> "" & Cells(i, 16) < 1.51 Then
                     GotMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 8 & 17), Range("H1:H,Q1:Q" & lrow), 0) & _
                     WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(l, 16), Range("P:P" & lrow2), 0)
                         If i + l <> GotMatch Then
                             Cells(i + l).EntireRow.Delete
                         End If
                End If
            Next
          Next
```

Comment: I guess you mean less than or equal to 1.5? Your "after running" has removed a  row that has 1.5 in col A? You don't need to use `< 1.51`, you can use `<=1.5`

Comment: Also I'm confused in your "after running" you have `1.25 | 30.5 | 30` twice - shouldn't that only exist once?

Comment: FYI `Range("H:H,Q:Q").End(xlUp).row` is always 1  Same for `P:P`

Comment: `For i = 8 & 17 To lrow` - looks off

Comment: @jamheadart When AB&C conditions are met on the same row and there are 8 rows it should delete half the rows and leave 4 rows for `1.25 | 30.5 | 30` if there were 9 rows it should still delete 4 rows since it could not match to an even number. for each row with the exact same data if should turn 2 rows into 1 row if only 1 row is left it should leave it. hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Not to be overly harsh here, but you should really take one of the free VBA tutorials that are in various places around the internet. Almost every single line in your code has syntactical or logical errors.

Comment: @Warcupine I would agree. Im not great at it and honestly I dont normally use it for much more then a few simple marcos every now and again.